# Swift iOS9 New Contacts Framework - How to retrieve only CNContact that has a valid email address?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

In the latest Contacts framework for iOS9, how to retrieve only CNContact that has a valid email address?

Current code:

```
func getContacts() -> [CNContact] {
    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    let predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "")
    let keysToFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey]

    do {
        return try contactStore.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(predicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
    } catch {
        return []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For now (iOS 9.0) it seems that no predicates ([see CNContact Predicates](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/CNContact_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015273-CH1-DontLinkElementID_56)) are available to filter contacts by email address!

You can't write a custom predicate to filter contacts, as the doc says: 
    *"Note that generic and compound predicates are not supported by the Contacts framework"*

But of course you can do it "manually", I show you an example using fast enumeration:

```
let contactStore = CNContactStore()
fetchRequest.unifyResults = true //True should be the default option
do {
    try contactStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey])) {
        (contact, cursor) -> Void in
        if (!contact.emailAddresses.isEmpty){
            //Add to your array
        }
    }
}
catch{
    print("Handle the error please")
}
```

**Note**:

In newer versions of Swift, the call to `contactStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest` needs to be updated to:

```
try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor])) {
```

Comment: How would you use this with a CNContactPickerViewController? Is it possible? Or would you have to create a new View controller to select your contacts?

Comment: You can look at the method: predicateForEnablingContact of CNContactPickerViewController

Comment: @adreacipriani, `fetchRequest:CNContactFetchRequest` have predicate variable and we can find particular contact for a predicate, right? Can you show an example?