# Swift Using Contacts Framework, search using phone number to get Name and User Image

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, contacts-framework

I have an API that returns phone numbers in format: +1415xxxxxxx (E164)

Right now these numbers are put into a Cell of a UITableView and are presented as expected, however I'd like to be able to search the users contacts on the phone to see if the there is a match - if so also pass back the Firstname, last name and known photo.

Looking at the Apple pages (https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html) I need to

```
 import ContactsUI
```

but then Im unsure, do I load the contactDB into a dictionary and then search it? I can find lots of things on searching via name and less on searching via number:

```
  let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("Sam")
```

Im trying to get to a function that I can call, that searches using the PhoneNumber and gives me back the FirstName, FamilyName and Image.

```
  func searchForContactUsingNumber(PhoneNumber: String)
 {

 // Search Via phoneNumber
  let store = CNContactStore()
  let contacts = try store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber), keysToFetch:[CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey,CNContactImageData])

  return FirstName, GivenName,UIImage

 }
```

I get the feeling I'm going about this backwards but not sure which way is forwards.. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you try your code? What errors do you get and what is not working?

Comment: The code isn't right at all, I dont think there is a CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingPhoneNumber, I just adapted Name to illustrate what Im trying to get too.

Comment: There does not appear to be a predicate that allows you to pass in a phone number and return a contact. Probably because this is a new API. I have written some code that returns a list of contact identifiers that match a phone number which you could then use to return a contact. Is this of interest?

Comment: Actually I have just realised that I can trivially return a list of contacts instead. You could then extract all the required information from that contact array. Is this of interest to you?

Comment: Yes Please :) That would be most helpful

Comment: OK - I have to go out but I will add an answer later (at least 4 hours but maybe more).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to get this example up-and-running quickly I used the following sources of info:

[Filter non-digits from string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29971505/558933)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32700339/558933

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-contacts-framework/

The code block below includes the authorisation check because I had to get it working in order to test in the simulator. The code is just the Single-View Apps view controller and you can connect up a `UIButton` in the Storyboard to the `findContactInfoForPhoneNumber:` method to get if to run. Output is to the console - you will need to replace these `print` statements with something else.

If you are not interested in the full view controller code then just look at the `searchForContactUsingPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String)` method. I've followed Apple's advice in the docs to run the `CNContact` framework asynchronously.

The code strips all the `+`, `-` and `(` symbols that could be in a phone number and just matches the digits so the phone number you pass in to match MUST be exactly the same.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ContactsTest
//
//  Created by Robotic Cat on 13/04/2016.
//

import UIKit
import Contacts

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - App Logic
    func showMessage(message: String) {
        // Create an Alert
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        // Add an OK button to dismiss
        let dismissAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in
        }
        alertController.addAction(dismissAction)

        // Show the Alert
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func requestForAccess(completionHandler: (accessGranted: Bool) -> Void) {
        // Get authorization
        let authorizationStatus = CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(CNEntityType.Contacts)

        // Find out what access level we have currently
        switch authorizationStatus {
        case .Authorized:
            completionHandler(accessGranted: true)

        case .Denied, .NotDetermined:
            CNContactStore().requestAccessForEntityType(CNEntityType.Contacts, completionHandler: { (access, accessError) -> Void in
                if access {
                    completionHandler(accessGranted: access)
                }
                else {
                    if authorizationStatus == CNAuthorizationStatus.Denied {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            let message = "\(accessError!.localizedDescription)\n\nPlease allow the app to access your contacts through the Settings."
                            self.showMessage(message)
                        })
                    }
                }
            })

        default:
            completionHandler(accessGranted: false)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func findContactInfoForPhoneNumber(sender: UIButton) {

        self.searchForContactUsingPhoneNumber("(888)555-1212)")
    }

    func searchForContactUsingPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0), { () -> Void in
            self.requestForAccess { (accessGranted) -> Void in
                if accessGranted {
                    let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
                    var contacts = [CNContact]()
                    var message: String!

                    let contactsStore = CNContactStore()
                    do {
                        try contactsStore.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys)) {
                            (contact, cursor) -> Void in
                            if (!contact.phoneNumbers.isEmpty) {
                                let phoneNumberToCompareAgainst = phoneNumber.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet).joinWithSeparator("")
                                for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {
                                    if let phoneNumberStruct = phoneNumber.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
                                        let phoneNumberString = phoneNumberStruct.stringValue
                                        let phoneNumberToCompare = phoneNumberString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet).joinWithSeparator("")
                                        if phoneNumberToCompare == phoneNumberToCompareAgainst {
                                            contacts.append(contact)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if contacts.count == 0 {
                            message = "No contacts were found matching the given phone number."
                        }
                    }
                    catch {
                        message = "Unable to fetch contacts."
                    }

                    if message != nil {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            self.showMessage(message)
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        // Success
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            // Do someting with the contacts in the main queue, for example
                            /*
                             self.delegate.didFetchContacts(contacts) <= which extracts the required info and puts it in a tableview
                             */
                            print(contacts) // Will print all contact info for each contact (multiple line is, for example, there are multiple phone numbers or email addresses)
                            let contact = contacts[0] // For just the first contact (if two contacts had the same phone number)
                            print(contact.givenName) // Print the "first" name
                            print(contact.familyName) // Print the "last" name
                            if contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactImageDataKey) {
                                if let contactImageData = contact.imageData {
                                    print(UIImage(data: contactImageData)) // Print the image set on the contact
                                }
                            } else {
                                // No Image available

                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: So Im very close to getting this. 
If I copy your code into my swift page, and run: 

`self.searchForContactUsingPhoneNumber("+1987654321") // Where +1987654321 has an address entry it gives me that address entry's name and UIIamge details. As expected, Thank you!`

However if I put the same code into the 

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {`

function, I immediately get error: 


`[]
fatal error: Index out of range`

Where its not loaded the contacts array. 
I was going to return the name and UI image using a tuple.

Comment: I can't tell what's going wrong from the comment but I can guess. The code clearly works but it sounds like you have a logic issue where you return the `contact` data. The way the code works is that you add the found `contact` into your data model and then update the table with `reloadData` or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` rather than returning a value. This is because the code runs asynchronously outside the main queue. I recommend you use the debugger and find where the code crashes but it sounds like you are trying to access the `contacts` value before the code has returned.

Comment: That was my thoughts, because the job is running in a different thread and completes at a different time. I'll keep going. It clearly works, Thank you :)

Comment: If you can't solve it then ask a new question and post the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

ContactList with ContactUI Framework with Custom Tableview

```
import UIKit

class ContactCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var PersonNameLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var PersonMobileNOLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var PersonImage: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var PersonEmailLabel: UILabel!
}
```

ContactViewController

```
import ContactsUI

class ContactViewController: UIViewController,CNContactPickerDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
var objects  = [CNContact]() 
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! 
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  self.getContacts()
}
func getContacts() {
    let store = CNContactStore()

    switch CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts){
    case .authorized:
        self.retrieveContactsWithStore(store: store)

    // This is the method we will create
    case .notDetermined:
        store.requestAccess(for: .contacts){succeeded, err in
            guard err == nil && succeeded else{
                return
            }
            self.retrieveContactsWithStore(store: store)

        }
    default:
        print("Not handled")
    }

}
func retrieveContactsWithStore(store: CNContactStore)
{


 let keysToFetch = [CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName), CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey] as [Any]
    let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
    var cnContacts = [CNContact]()
    do {
        try store.enumerateContacts(with: request){
            (contact, cursor) -> Void in
            if (!contact.phoneNumbers.isEmpty) {
            }

            if contact.isKeyAvailable(CNContactImageDataKey) {
                if let contactImageData = contact.imageData {
                    print(UIImage(data: contactImageData)) // Print the image set on the contact
                }
            } else {
                // No Image available

            }
            if (!contact.emailAddresses.isEmpty) {
            }
            cnContacts.append(contact)
             self.objects = cnContacts
        }
    } catch let error {
        NSLog("Fetch contact error: \(error)")
    }

    NSLog(">>>> Contact list:")
    for contact in cnContacts {
        let fullName = CNContactFormatter.string(from: contact, style: .fullName) ?? "No Name"
        NSLog("\(fullName): \(contact.phoneNumbers.description)")
    }
   self.tableView.reloadData()   
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.objects.count
}
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ContactCell  
    let contact = self.objects[indexPath.row]
print("theis my contact arrau \(self.objects.count)")
    let formatter = CNContactFormatter()  
    cell.PersonNameLabel.text = formatter.string(from: contact )
if let actualNumber = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value as? CNPhoneNumber {
    //Get the label of the phone number

    //Strip out the stuff you don't need
    print(actualNumber.stringValue)  
cell.PersonMobileNOLabel.text = actualNumber.stringValue
}
else{
    cell.PersonMobileNOLabel.text = "N.A "
}
if let actualEmail = (contact as AnyObject).emailAddresses?.first?.value as String? {
    print(actualEmail)  
    cell.PersonEmailLabel.text = actualEmail
}
else{
    cell.PersonEmailLabel.text = "N.A "
}
if let imageData = contact.imageData {
    //If so create the image
    let userImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
    cell.PersonImage.image = userImage;
}

else{
    cell.PersonImage.image = UIImage (named: "N.A")
}
    return cell
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

import UIKit
import Contacts

class PhonebookVC: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var ContactTblView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var SearchTxtField: SkyFloatingLabelTextField!



var contacts = [CNContact]()
var NameArray = [String]()
var NumberArray = [String]()

var filteredName = [String]()
var filteredNumber = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getContacts()
    SearchTxtField.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func SearchFunc(_ sender: UIButton) {

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.filteredName.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ContactTblView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! PhonebookCell
    cell.ContactName.text = self.filteredName[indexPath.row]
    cell.ContactNumber.text = self.filteredNumber[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}




/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

extension PhonebookVC
{

```
func getContacts()
{
    let status = CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts)
    if status == .denied || status == .restricted {
        presentSettingsActionSheet()
        return
    }

    // open it

    let contactStore = CNContactStore()
    contactStore.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { granted, error in
        guard granted else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.presentSettingsActionSheet()
            }
            return
        }

        // get the contacts
        let keys = [
            CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
            CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as CNKeyDescriptor] as [Any]
        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
        do {
            try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request){
                (contact, stop) in
                // Array containing all unified contacts from everywhere
                self.contacts.append(contact)
                var i = 0
                for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {

                        print("\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)\n \(phoneNumber.value.stringValue)")

                        self.NameArray.append("\(contact.givenName) \(contact.familyName)")
                        self.NumberArray.append(phoneNumber.value.stringValue)
                        i = i+1

                }
                i = 0

                self.filteredName   = self.NameArray
                self.filteredNumber = self.NumberArray

                self.ContactTblView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print("unable to fetch contacts")
        }
    }
}

func presentSettingsActionSheet() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Permission to Contacts", message: "This app needs access to contacts in order to Send top-up.", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Settings", style: .default) { _ in
        let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

}

extension PhonebookVC : UITextFieldDelegate
{
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        self.filteredName.removeAll()
        self.filteredNumber.removeAll()

```
    if(self.NameArray.count != 0){


        var mystring = "\(textField.text ?? "")\(string)"
        if(textField.text?.count == 1 && string == ""){

            mystring = ""
        }
        var i = 0
        for ContactName in self.NameArray {
            let name = ContactName
            let range = name.lowercased().range(of: mystring, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil,   locale: nil)

            if range != nil {
                if(filteredName.count == 0){

                    filteredName = [ContactName]
                    filteredNumber = [NumberArray[i]]

                }else{

                    filteredName.append(ContactName)
                    filteredNumber.append(NumberArray[i])
                }

            }
            i = i+1
        }

        if(string == "" && (textField.text?.count == 1)){

            self.filteredName   = self.NameArray
            self.filteredNumber = self.NumberArray

        }

        self.ContactTblView.reloadData()
    }
    return true
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to index phone numbers in your own database so you can lookup for the contact identifier.

Comment: Can someone please confirm this?

Comment: I don't think so